# Get rid of format warning for simple statements without braces in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ and in setting `Code Style` - `Java` - `Wrapping and Braces`
[image]

`Force braces` for `if`, `for` and `while` are set to be `Do not force` which allows simple statements without braces, e.g.

```java
if (a == b) 
    return true;
```

The program for simple statements without braces compiles without error, but the IDE still keeps reminding me to add braces for simple statements.

[image]

How can I get rid of those warnings in IntelliJ?

Comment: I don't get any warning with your code on the latest version. Which version are you using?

Comment: My version is 2018.2  @EugenCovaci

Comment: Quite old .......

Comment: The code style doesn't inform the warnings IIRC. Check under _More actions_ for the option to disable the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an inspection called *Control flow statement without braces*. You can disable it in `Preferences | Editor | Inspections | Java | Code style issues | Control flow statement without braces`. Or by typing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the warning, followed by <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> and selecting `Disable inspection`.